# How to change font dynamically in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to change my font dynamically. I want to apply Ghost font on the text field.
For that i am importing **the_hungry_ghost.ttf** file in Resources folder.
And in `Info.plist` file writing this code.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>the_hungry_ghost.ttf</string>
</array>
```

To apply this font,

```
textmemo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"The Hungry Ghost" size:16.0];
```

But the issue is when i am running this code in simulator it works
But in device it is not responding.

Comment: Try to delete the app from dvice first

Comment: Did you tried a clean / build.

Comment: check the font name.because,simulator are not case sensitive,but,iphone is case sensitive..!

Comment: Did you check it in font Book ??? use the same name as is shown in Font Book software.

Comment: What happened with custom fonts now? I think that issue was solved.. :-|

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with textmemo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"the_hungry_ghost" size:16.0];

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];
```

First clean delete and clean all targets and the run yor application

To clean all targets **`shift + Command + K`**